# ElementNotVisibleException in IE10 and IE11

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have a test case working for chrome driver.

Then I execute it for ie10 and ie-11 driver (using a BrowserStack), and it throws an exeception (see below) basically I select an element using

`IWebElement myElement = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*/input[@type='file']"));`

method. When I run

```
myElement.SendKeys(@"C:\Users\hello\Documents\images\wallpaper1.jpg");
```

it throws the exception below.

```
    OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : Element is not displayed
 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 61 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:33'
    System info: host: '5-255-92-204', ip: '5.255.92.204', os.name: 'windows', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=10, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:31891/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
    Session ID: 3380bb44-31a8-45a6-90c1-84447a153e7a
```

But the element is inside the page.

Comment: You cannot interact with elements that are disabled or not visible. Have you tried a Thread.Sleep to wait for the page to load?  You'll need to provide your Page source for people to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Two things. First, this issue has nothing to do with `By.XPath`. The element is being found just fine. Second, I strongly suspect that the developer of your site has decided that `<input type='file'>` elements are just ugly, and is trying to provide a "prettier" alternative. If your developer (or the developer of your JavaScript widget toolkit) has done this in the most common way, then [this commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/18a2092eacd8484bb49ea394dc042cb443583eb4) to the IE driver code base will be of interest to you.